# CorelDraw X6 Macro to insert Date using DTPicker Control

Tags: vba, date, coreldraw

I'm trying to insert a date into a label. I have written the following code. I can select a date by clicking on the arrow and the calendar pops up.  The "CANCEL" button is working, but when I click "OK" I cannot get it to insert on the label. The label is a regular Corel document with text and images. I tried inserting a rectangle toolbox to see if I can get it to insert the date in there by using X,Y coordinates but that didn't work.
I basically need to know how to insert `DTPicker.Value` onto the label.

```
Sub ShowIt()
    Calendar.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()
    a = DTPicker1.Value
    b = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)
    DTPicker1.Value = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "mm/dd/yy")
End Sub

Private Sub Calendar_Activate()
    Me.DTPicker1.Value = Date    
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This :
1. Add a button on macro form
2. Select the rectangle
3. Click the button
4. Macro will read X, Y Pos of the rectangle, then create text and positioning it on the center of the rectangle

```
ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrCenter

XPos = Activeselection.PositionX 'XPos of the rect

YPos = Activeselection.PositionY 'YPos of the rect

Set s = ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(0, 0, CStr(Date))

s.PositionX=XPos

s.PositionY=YPos
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm getting the following errors when using this code: Run-Time error '438. Object doesn't support this property or method. This error refers to 'ReferencePoint', 'PositionX', 'PositionY', 'CreateArtisticText'. When I try to retype these properties, they do no come up on the object browser. Any idea why I can't use them?

Comment: I think I was able to fix some of them and right now I'm having a problem with this line: Set s = ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(0, 0, CStr(Date)).It says that the object doesn't support this property or method. I have added a few libraries. Am I missing anything?

Comment: By the way, I found a programing guide for VBA for CorelDraw X4. http://www.ahearncutting.com/download/dvba_pg.pdf.60e4d393e525b27a2fc8b6b913c480c6. It's useful, however I'm using CorelDraw X6.

Comment: Just found the one for CorelDraw X6; http://www.ett.bme.hu/upload/1221836168454.9_5811338cca872cd32e0cdf072e2d011c/Coreldraw_Macro_Programming_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the previous code separated from your code.

```
Sub Macro1()

  ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrCenter

  XPos = Activeselection.PositionX 

  YPos = Activeselection.PositionY 

  Set s = ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(0, 0, CStr(Date))

  s.PositionX=XPos

  s.PositionY=YPos

End Sub
```

1. Select the rectangle
2. Click macro
3. The macro should work perfectly to create and place date at center on rectangle. BUT, the date is NOW (date when macro executed).
4. Then you should modify " CStr(Date)" to the value where the date is referred.

Comment: It keeps complaining about ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText. Error: "Object doesn't support property or method".

Comment: Ok I was able to use those properties by using for e.g. CorelDRAW.ActiveDocument.ActivePage.ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText. The problem I'm having now is that when I use   CorelDRAW.ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrCenter, it throws the following error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".Any ideas?

Comment: Also, when I do Set sh = CorelDRAW.ActiveDocument.ActivePage.ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(0, 0, CStr(DTPicker1.Value)), the debugger tells me "sh = Nothing".

Comment: Anajz, you can edit a previous post to include new content.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work as requested :

```
ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrCenter

XPos = Activeselection.PositionX 'XPos of the rect

YPos = Activeselection.PositionY 'YPos of the rect

Set s = ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(0, 0, CStr(Date))

s.PositionX=XPos

s.PositionY=YPos
```

BUT : 
He did not use Corel Draw..... :) 
https://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_community/f/101/t/51007

Comment: Yes, my fault. I didn't realize I was using PhotoPaint instead of CorelDraw. However, I have tried that code but didn't seem to work for me. I'm using the code below and maybe I could implement your somehow as mine is inserting the date in the wrong place. I've tried using Shape instead of Page but then I get an error in the last line sDate.Move 0, -sDate.SizeHeight. Thanks for your help.  @Yakk

Comment: Dim Page As Page
    Dim x As Double, y As Double
    Dim strMyDate As String
    Dim sDate As Shape
    Dim Shape As Shape
                                                                                                      strMyDate = CStr(DTPicker1.Value)
    
   If strMyDate <> "" Then
        For Each Page In ActiveDocument.Pages
        Page.ActiveLayer.Shapes.All.GetPositionEx cdrTopLeft, x, y
      
        Set sDate = Page.ActiveLayer.CreateArtisticText(x, y, strMyDate)
        Next Page
      
        sDate.Move 0, -sDate.SizeHeight
    End If
    Unload Me
End Sub

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to post code the right way as displayed in the above comments.

Answer (score -1):

"Object variable or With block variable not set".

No Active document there.

I think you should create NEW Document first

Comment: Please include a code example to improve your answer.

Comment: I have a new document and I'm clicking on the rectangle created with "Rectangle Tool". Then I go to tools menu and click on Macro Editor which takes me to the user form code. Why isn't it recognizing my document?

Comment: Private Sub OK_Click()
     CorelDRAW.ActiveDocument.ReferencePoint = cdrCenter      'This line throws a  "Object variable or With block variable not set" error.                    End Sub