# Where do I insert this code to create the macro in CorelDraw X7?

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I'm referring to this post here:[CorelDraw X6 Macro to insert Date using DTPicker Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389241/coreldraw-x6-macro-to-insert-date-using-dtpicker-control)

I am creating a template for everyday use for saving artwork proofs to send onto customers for visual approval. I'd like the following boxes to auto populate the following information:
1. A box that will populate today's date
2. A box that will populate the work order number based on the first 6 digits of the filename
3. A box that will populate the filename as a whole

The rectangles/boxes will already be in the document that gets imported. I just want to create a macro, or multiple...to click in order to fill these boxes before exporting to a PDF for customers approval.

I'm a total coding n00b and can't find specific directions on where to copy the code listed in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

In the Corel Draw menu, go to "Tools" then "Macros" then "Macro editor".

After that, you can paste it in the right hand side of the screen, on the white empty box.

That should do it.